# Django: translate in a different language than current language

Tags: python, django

I would like to notify the user in case he's viewing the site in a language that doesn't correspond to his first preference in the ACCEPT_LANGUAGE header.

For this reason I would like to present the message to the user in his first prefered language rather than the one he's currently viewing the web-site.

Is it possible with django (views and templates) to translate a string in a specific language indipendently than the current language?

Thanks

### Example:

Italian user visits for the first time the site, but the english version.
I want him to see a message in italian like: "Preferiresti vedere il sito in Italiano?"

Answer (score 0):

You might find some use in the functions `activate(language)` and `deactivate(language)` located in `django.utils.translation`. I'm not sure about the efficiency of this, I imagine it is slow, but it might do the job :)

Answer (score 0):

You can find your answers here:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/i18n/#using-translations-in-your-own-projects